# Adding static images to theme

Tags: theming, media

In `page.tpl.php`, I add some static images by using :

```
$bolo = path_to_theme() . '/images/bolo.gif';
....
<img src="<?php print $bolo ?>" alt="bolo" width="71" height="125">
```

How I can do the same by using a preprocess function (like `theme_image()` for example) in `template.php` and calling the (image)variable in `page.tpl.php` ?
It seems easy, but I can't perform it.
Thanks

Bolo

Comment: theme_image() is a theme function. Preprocess functions are things like template_preprocess_html(), template_preprocess_page(), etc. Have you tried doing this in template_preprocess_page(&$vars) and setting $vars['bolo'] = path_to_theme()... and then printing $bolo in your page.tpl?

Answer (score 0):

You can to use `hook_prorocess_page` for this.

In the theme's template.php file, add the following function (make sure it doesn't exist. if so, append the function content to the existing file)

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $image = ... // Generate your image's img tag here, optionally wrap with some DIVs.
  $vars['my_image'] = $image;
}
```

Now, you can access this variable as `$my_image`.